# Setting permissions for custom shell scripts and directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My question is about permissions and ownership settings for my custom shell scripts and the custom shell script directory itself. This is only for security on my personal machine, but I'd like to know best practices for any situation.

My script directory is /usr/local/scripts/

- Should I give myself write privileges to my own scripts? Or should root be the only one?
- Should everyone else have read-only permission?
- Should root have ownership over any of my scripts/directory?

I'm still learning UNIX permissions, so trying to wrap my head around the implications of certain files having certain permissions still eludes me to an extent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend you to put your unprivileged scripts (scripts that do not need to be executed as root) **inside your home folder** (it is a common practice to put them in `~/bin`, some distributions even add this directory to your `$PATH`, so you can execute them from any directory). That way you do not have to write to a root-owned directory, avoiding the need of becoming root to edit them.

About execute permissions, almost always, if you have read permissions you will be able to execute it, either by copying to another location and giving it execute permissions, or by launching the interpreter with the script as first argument (eg. `bash my_script.sh`).

I see no problem in giving others read and execute permissions to my scripts, remember that they will be executed with the executing user's permissions, not yours. Anyway, if they have the knowledge, they will be able to write and execute them.

If you put scripts outside your home directory, they should be owned and only editable by root (they can be readable and executable by everyone). That way, if root executes it, it knows that no one else can have changed the file, so it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I give myself write privileges to my own scripts? Or should root be the only one?

I don't see a security reason not to give yourself write privileges - it is just inconvenient to manually maintain scripts in system directories. If these scripts are for personal use, it is best to keep your scripts somewhere in your home directory, probably `~/bin` and then add that directory to the beginning of your `PATH` variable through your shell's startup script in your home directory. That way, you don't need any special permissions to test your scripts.

> Should everyone else have read-only permission?

Unless you want to keep the contents of your script a secret, it should not be a problem to give others both `read` and `execute` permissions.

> Should root have ownership over any of my scripts/directory?

The important thing is that other users must not have write access to the scripts. As long as the owner is you and you are the sole member of the group assigned to the file, you don't need to worry about security. It is just not convenient to have your scripts outside your home directory, but otherwise things should be fine.

Comment: Adding `~/bin` to the _beginning_ of your PATH creates a security vulnerability, where if someone could manage to create, say `ls` in there, it would be executed instead of the system `ls`. It's pretty common to add your own ~/bin on your path, but you should add it at the _end_. If you actually want to override a system command, I suggest using an _alias_.

Comment: Point taken. I see the similarities between this and adding `.` to the PATH.

There are situations where I find putting a `bin` directory (somewhere inside $HOME) at the start is useful - for example, if I have a local installation of newer versions of `perl` or `python`. Thus, scripts which use `#!/bin/env perl` in the shebang would use the perl installed in my home directory.